# How to scale drawing at random size using mouseClicked function without the drawing losing it's overall shape p5.js

Tags: function, scale, mouseclick-event, p5.js

I have a canvas with a drawing in it. My goal is to generate the drawing using the mouseClicked function and to have it drawn at an arbitrary size anywhere on the canvas (using the mouseClicked function) without it losing its shape. The shapes scale correctly and they seem to be going to the correct x and y coordinates; however, when the drawing is scaled down, the shapes are spread out and when the drawing is scaled up, the shapes move closer together. How can I scale the drawing so that it's relative to the x and y coordinates and doesn't lose it's overall shape?

```js
function setup() { 
  createCanvas(800, 800);
    background('red');
} 

function draw() {}
  
  function drawMickey(mickeyX, mickeyY, mickeySize){
   
   //ears
   stroke('black');
 strokeWeight(4);
   fill('black');
 ellipse(mickeyX, mickeyY, mickeySize, mickeySize);
 ellipse(mickeyX + 170, mickeyY, mickeySize, mickeySize);
  
   
   //head
   stroke('black');
 strokeWeight(4);
   fill('black');
 ellipse(mickeyX + 85, mickeyY + 90, mickeySize * 1.5, mickeySize * 1.5);

  
   
}

function mouseClicked(){
  var mickeySize = random(0, width / 5);
  drawMickey(mouseX, mouseY, mickeySize)
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.10/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do for questions like this is to get out some graph paper and draw some examples. Consider where the center of the bottom circle is, and where the top circles are in relation to that.

You probably want to position the top circles in relation to the bottom circle, while taking into account the size of the circles.

Here's a small example:

```
function setup() { 
  createCanvas(800, 800);
} 

function draw() {

    var circleX = 600;
    var circleY = 400;
    var circleSize = 50;

    ellipse(circleX, circleY, circleSize, circleSize);
    ellipse(circleX - circleSize/2, circleY - circleSize/2, circleSize/2, circleSize/2);
    ellipse(circleX + circleSize/2, circleY - circleSize/2, circleSize/2, circleSize/2);
}
```

Like I said, the best thing you can do is draw out a bunch of examples until you notice a pattern. If you're still having trouble, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like this in a new question post. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably look into the `map()` function, which re-maps a number from one range to another. You can use it to get the distance to draw the ellipse according to the size, `map(mickeySize, 0, width / 5, 20, 85)`. Correct usage of the function here: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/map
Hope this gets you on the right track.